# How to upload images and xml file into a maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, bitbucket

I'm working on a videogame with a my friend. We are working with Eclipse and we are using maven. We use BitBucket to synchronize the project but now we have a problem. I'm doing the GUI but I don't know how to upload the images and an xml file in the project and synchronize this with bitbucket. Now I'm using the path of the file that is on my desktop. There is a way to load all the files and import these into the project? I'm searching a solution that is correct also when we must export the project in a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Place the files in the source folder resources, and access them not as File, but as

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/a/b/c.png");
// URL "..... myproject.jar!/a/b/c,png"
```

or direct as:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/d.xml");
```

Case-sensitive.

This zips the files together with the .class code in the jar file.

Comment: When i write the code in eclipse there is an error:Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object EDIT. I've resolved that problem. But now there is another error. What is the path that I must insert to insert my files?

Comment: If can help this is the structure of my folders on eclipse [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbh963fzvntsux7/Schermata%202014-06-13%20alle%2015.56.43.png)

Comment: You need to a source folder with the following name: src/main/resource, this is the default resources folder the maven uses. For this directory you can get the files o the image in the way descript from Joop above

Comment: (a bit late) Resources "src/main/resources" and `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/grafo.xml")` where MyClass is in the same jar.