# Read an image file within the Eclipse Project in java

Tags: java

I am working on a simple 2D Sidescroller and I use this :

`bgData = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\"
                + "Workspace\\Sidescroller\\src\\data\\bg.png");`

Since it reads a file within the code base, why cant I access it?

Exception got:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you show your code please? What is the errormessage you got?

Comment: I am sure someone already asked that question (yeah, maybe not exactly with this path :P). Post what error you are getting. I.e.: "IOException"? And edit your question or look again.

Comment: I get : 
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206646/how-to-upload-images-and-xml-file-into-a-maven-project-in-eclipse/24206839#24206839

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem is that you're using `\` char as part of the path.

Instead try changing:

```
bgData = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\" 
+ "Workspace\\Sidescroller\\src\\data\\bg.png");
```

for

```
bgData = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder/"
+ "Workspace/Sidescroller/src/data/bg.png");
```

Comment: No. That is not what I want. The 'data' folder in within the project. I want to read the file within the project. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Thor for better help sooner please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I figured out what was wrong. It seems java was looking in the package folder for the pictures.